# Disable MathJax in Org Mode html export

Tags: org-export

How do I prevent Org Mode from including MathJax when exporting as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the mathjax HTML template to be blank:

```
(setf org-html-mathjax-template "")
```

This should stop org from exporting any mathjax stuff at all.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Math-formatting-in-HTML-export) says:

```
   If you prefer, you can also request that LaTeX fragments are
processed into small images that will be inserted into the browser page.
Before the availability of MathJax, this was the default method for Org
files.  This method requires that the ‘dvipng’ program, ‘dvisvgm’ or
‘imagemagick’ suite is available on your system.  You can still get this
processing with

     #+OPTIONS: tex:dvipng

     #+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm

 or:

     #+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
```

Comment: My documents do not include any LaTaX. Though I am sure if I did want to render LaTaX without MathJax, yours is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I see: I misinterpreted the question. Fortunately, Alan Third did not :-)